# Suggestion on geoloaction and application type

Tags: c#, service, geolocation, ip-geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to make a program using c# that will allow me to determine where a computer of mine is located using geolocation services. I was wondering what you would suggest as far as geolocatio APis go and whether you think i should just make a background process or a windows service or if it is even possible to make it a service. I've heard of one by w3c, google, windows, and skyhook. I'm hoping to be able to determine an address from it and I was also hoping that the service would be free (even if its only for a few look-ups a day.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear why you're asking about background process or Windows service.  You application will not be able to get the location of the computer from services like google.

I suggest you install the Geosense driver for Windows 7 to add a Location driver (see http://geosenseforwindows.com/ ) I would then use something like the Location and Sensor interop library to query that sensor to find the rough location of the computer. (see http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SensorsAndLocation/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2359)

If that's not what you we wanting to do; please provide more information.

Comment: Why would it not be able to get it from a service like google as seen here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Geocoding means converting a lat/long value to an address (reverse geolocation is converting an address to a lat/long value).  How would you know your computer's lat/long unless you entered it manually?

Comment: Oh gotcha. Sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for the help! But is there any of that using your ip address? For example when google maps tells where you are based off of your ip...

Comment: Geosense supports  using the IP.  That generally doesn't give you the location of the computer though, it gives you the location of your ISP.